# How can I add a "force quit" button to my Unity top-bar?

Tags: 11.10, unity, applet

The title says it all.

In olden times, one could right click the bar, go to "add to panel", and then add the "force quit" applet from the list. Apparently that doesn't work any more.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where is force quit?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/72017/where-is-force-quit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install indicator-forceclose. There is an article on it [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/06/quickly-kill-rogue-apps-in-ubuntu-with-indicator-forceclose). The home-page is launchpad.net/indicator-forceclose.

To install, extract the archive, `cd` into the folder (use `cd /path/to/folder`), and run:

```
    sudo python setup.py install
```

You can also add a similar program to the unity launcher, which lets you freeze/unfreeze programs as well as kill them. See [this page](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/force-quit-applet-unity-launcher/) for details.