# How to Force Quit a not responding application?

Tags: vlc, kill

VLC doesnt quit. How do I force quit the application?

Comment: **I tried using vlc's PID with the killall commmand but it returned as process not found**

Comment: open a terminal, type `xkill` + Return. Then click on the application's window. Must be a dupe of something.

Comment: killall expect a process name rather then a PID

Comment: I tried **sudo kill -9 PID** right now and it worked for me.

Comment: Unnecessarily complicated, see my comment above.

Comment: Mored possible dupes: http://askubuntu.com/questions/13441/how-to-kill-applications http://askubuntu.com/questions/194471/how-can-a-frozen-locked-up-program-app-be-closed http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes

Comment: @JacobVlijm Using xkill is much easier if a certain window stops responding but what happend was i did quit VLC but it was running in the background,so the VLC window wasnt available for me to close, so had I to use the alternative method. :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Run this command to find out the PID it is using

```
ps aux | grep vlc
```

then run

```
sudo kill -9 <PID NUMBER>
```

Comment: I would rather be interesting finding the cause for this. And get it fixed by raising bug.

Comment: I believe this answer is ambiguous.
It possibly works if you know that PID is meant to be a number?
to type the second command in literally I think might fail
better to wrap the PID in <> e.g. sudo kill -9 <PID NUMBER>

Comment: That's pretty basic. PID is always a number.

Comment: @NZDev updated the answer.

Answer (score 36):

You can use based on name `pkill`

```
pkill vlc
```

If that doesn't work, try:

```
pkill -9 vlc
```

Comment: I removed the `sudo` because i) you should never run `sudo` unless necessary and ii) in this case, that would have killed _all_ cases of vlc running on the system. Not only those belonging to the OP. I also removed the `-9` because that is very aggressive and is not necessary here.

Comment: I used `-9` because OP want "force"

Comment: Yes, I realized which is why I added it back. Still, it should be used as a last resort, not on the first try and not with `sudo` unless you know what you're doing. Don't get me wrong, this is a good answer, that's my upvote there :)

Comment: I guess :) and for those who have more than just one e.g. `vlc` instance launched using `xkill` is a good way to resolve the problem

Comment: Thanks, this saves me plenty reboots

Comment: `-9` only thing that actually worked for me